# ¿La tabla Persona contiene a Usuario como atributo? o al revés?

Tags: base-de-datos, uml, atributos

Alguien puede ser tan amable y explicarme si la tabla Persona tiene como atributo a Usuario o al revés, o es Usuario otra tabla aparte que colinda con Persona?

Tengo un RF que es *Asignar Permisos* cuando creo a una nueva persona del sistema, pero se los tengo que asignar a usuarios *(los permisos)*, no a personas, . ¿O me equivocó? Por eso digo que si Persona tendría al atributo Usuario o al revés... por fa!! o necesitan más información.. Suele pasar que no puedo explicarme bien. Gracias por la atención prestada.

Comment: por lo usual cuando "creas" una persona, le asignas un tipo de usuario, este puede ser : admin, lector, suscriptor,etc. te en cuenta que puede haber varias personas con diferentes o iguales tipos de Usuario.

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pareceria que estas confundiendo usuario con ROL..

Usuario en general se usa como sinonimo de persona.. Y los usuarios (las personas, se dice usuarios porque que pasa si el usuario es una empresa?), tienen roles.

Los roles son los que tienen permisos. Y en general los usuarios tienen 1 o mas roles (ya eso depende del sistema) lo que le da mas o menos permisos.

Entonces existe una relacion `n a n` entre Roles y Personas.

Podria existir que no existieran los roles, y en ese caso habra una tabla de relacion entre Personas y Permisos, pero eso ya depende de la descrición funcional del sistema.